# Secure PHP File Upload Script

Tags: php, forms, file, upload, storage

I have asked this question twice i think, but this is the first time i have gotten close to this.  I am planning on allowing users to upload and download their files (.pdf, .doc, .exl, .ppt, .png, .jpg, .gif).

Will these tips be suffice:

http://blogs.sans.org/appsecstreetfighter/2009/12/28/8-basic-rules-to-implement-secure-file-uploads/

Also, is there a script I can utilize, i am new to php.

Comment: What script? All I see is some rules for proper handling.

Comment: tips look fine to me, some are dependent on your particular requirements\setup

Answer (score 26, accepted):

a late response, but i think your script should be based on this:
http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

it covers all aspects of security and explains all valid points. I hope this helps.

EDIT: The above link is dead, [here is a cached version of that article](http://web.archive.org/web/20140927111708/http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications).

Comment: This is a great guide

Comment: Cached link reference above does not have a cached copy of the source code file to download discussed in the cached article linked above.

Comment: There are several problems with this file upload security guide. 

The first is the whole concept of using a blacklist. Blacklisting is a losing proposition. You should whitelist the allowed extensions, check the uploaded file extension using the name you will save it as, and disallow access if the extension isn't in the whitelist. Blacklisting leaves you open any time a new vulnerability is discovered. Whitelisting is future proof.

Answer (score 9):

For Future readers, who are also new to php:

Before reading the guide mentioned in Ricki's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065880/1815624, which mentions a good guide and is defiantly a recommended read I would advise to read this answer first:

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32853/31943

then read the guide mentioned by Ricki at:

http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

After all that if you need further security, you should consider disconnecting from the internet. :P

Answer (score 3):

There is a million of file uploading scripts out there. [This one](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/file_upload.php) is not worse than the others.

Although the "protection" from uploading files other than pngs will not work (it only checks the name of the file).

Uploading files is quite safe - it's giving others the chance of downloading them that opens your server to certain types of attacks. The article you referenced does not mention two important points:

- **never serve any user provided files from the same domain as your webpage**. Have a separate domain for downloads. This way even if someone manages to upload a flash animation or a piece of HTML, your domain will not suffer from cross domain attack (eg if your application has a domain of example.org, you should serve user content from, say, downloads.example.com);
- always serve uploaded files with well controlled headers.

Comment: The danger in uploading is when programmers store the uploaded file in the document tree and check neither the suffix (*.php) nor the contents.  Once done it gives malicious users the ability to run an uncontrolled script on your server.  Yikes.  File uploaders should always check file names and content to be sure the file is exactly what the programmer expected.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain the statement, "Uploading files is quite safe - it's giving others the chance of downloading them that opens your server to certain types of attacks."  I provided an example.

Comment: @JBH Your advice is bad - following it will not get you any safety. And the "problem" you describe begins with serving users' files from the same domain as the rest of application, which is against the first of my two rules (and is followed by a lot of other silly errors). If you honestly follow the two rules I give above, your app is safe. As simple as that. Really.

Comment: Perhaps not bad, but maybe not what you wanted to talk about.  I'm not really interested in an argument, I just wanted to help people understand the problem.  Serving files from another domain may protect the first, but it doesn't protect the second.  I apologize if I offended you.  Cheers.