# How to change upload directory in my plugin uploader

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, wordpress

I have developed a plugin and in my plugin there is a custom  media uploader. When i upload any file from my plugin uploader that file is uploaded and saved in WordPress default `uploads/` folder.

But I want that when i upload file from my plugin uploader those files should be uploaded in a new folder inside Wordpress custom `uploads` folder so I search from google and found this code:

```
 <?php
     function upload_dir($dirs)                                    
{                                                             
        $dirs['subdir'] = '/my-uploads';                  
        $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/my-uploads'; 
        $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/my-uploads';  

        return $dirs;                                         
}                                                             

add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir');                       

   ?>
```

Now all files that are uploaded from (posts, pages etc) are also stored in that plugin folder.

I want that only those files which are uploaded from my plugin uploader should be saved in that `my-folder`, and rest of the files should be saved in WordPress default `uploads` folder...

Answer (score 6):

Right before the uploading code, use

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir');
```

Then after your uploading code, use:

```
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir');
```

That way, the filter only works for your plugin uploads and not on other places.

Comment: By doing this,it is saving files again in default uploads folder not in plugin folder...

Comment: Could you post an excerpt of your code? What normally should work is: add_filter, wp_handle_upload, remove_filter.

Comment: what do you mean by wp_handle_upload?

Comment: i haven't used this function... why is it used for?

Comment: @AasmaZafar This is a good answer. Did you try it out? It's better if you can show the code implementing the upload functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to handle the file processing yourself using plain PHP. When you process the form, try this:

```
$uploaddir = '/path/to/plugin/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
    echo 'success!';
else
    echo 'fail!';
```

and use `print_r($_FILES);` to debug.

Be very, very careful though - you're potentially creating a security risk. see [Secure PHP File Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script) for more info on that.

Answer (score 2):

It could have to do with the .htaccess settings. The .htaccess file creates limits as to what you can do. Or it could be some other setting outside of your file. Have you tried running this on more than 1 server to test it out?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [solution](https://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins/).

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$upload = wp_upload_dir();
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');

funcion my_upload_dir($upload) {
  $upload['subdir'] = '/sub-dir-to-use' . $upload['subdir'];
  $upload['path']       = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];
  $upload['url']        = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];
  return $upload;
}
```