# Is it safe to upload files after validating by mime_content_type() and imagecreatefromjpg()?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, file-type

I read a lot of articles (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script)) talking about secure file upload in PHP and I think this is the best way to make sure the file uploaded is safe.

First, I use mime_content_type() to check its file's type.
If it is JPG, JPEG or PNG, I'm gonna clone it with imagecreatefromjpg(), if success, save the new file and destroy the original.

I'm not sure this is safe enough or I need to do something else.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure PHP File Upload Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script)

Comment: @mistermartin I already read that. It did not mention what I'm asking here. They didn't saying anything about imagecreatefromjpg()

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) checks real file content to detect type

I did some testing for [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

1. When I created text file and named it "spoofily" `spoof.jpg`...
   the detected mime type was still **`text/plain`**
2. When I ran it on non existing file, it throws

   `PHP Warning: mime_content_type(not.exist):`

   `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

This means **`mime_content_type` checks *file content* for mime type**.

**Is it totally safe though?** It is safe enough to detect the **true** mime type, that's for sure ;)
However you should also check for things like size or sanitizing filename (when reused), for more security details, there is a nice answer on Security Stack: [Risks of a PHP image upload form](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form/32853#32853)

*note that in the PHP manual, this is under "Fileinfo Functions" menu => it kind of implies it uses file-read mechanisms, though it is true manual entry doesn't say this explicitly...*

Answer (score 0):

"mime_content_type" and "exif_imagetype" should not be used for security purposes because both of them allow spoofed files!

More details from link below:
https://straighttips.blogspot.com/2021/01/php-upload-spoofed-files.html