# Is it possible to use NSUrlSession to upload files to an FTP server?

Tags: c#, ftp, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession

I've been scouring the web for a few hours looking for a solution to a problem that I need to resolve with a Xamarin.iOS app that I've been developing. Most, if not all, of our customers in the field need to upload pictures that they attach to work orders (tickets), which go to an FTP on our backend. My coworker developed the Android app and from him I took the current method, based off of an FtpRequest casted to an FtpWebRequest. It works 90% of the time and uploads to the server reasonably quick if the user has a decent connection.

The problem? I need 100% of the time, and I need it to be in the background. I found that NSUrlSession seems to be my best bet for solving this issue, as it's native to iOS and has support for backgrounding. My only issue is that when I try to create the UploadTask with `session.CreateUploadTask`, it says "cannot read file at (path)" where path is: `file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/850CB1FE-9C2D-456C-8B5F-921DC8D5CEF5/Documents/PolarisPictures2/VUPSXOUTA722002799CMC5022017103109544681088_1.jpeg`. I've already confirmed that the file does exist on that path via printing out the file name using `foreach( var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "PolarisPictures2") )` Without using the file:// protocol, the error returns with "...is not a valid file:// url." So is it that I'm not accessing the file properly, or is it that there's simply no way to do what I'm trying to do?

And if there is no way, could anyone provide a solution that would best achieve the backgrounding capabilities that I require?

Appreciate it, guys.

Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
NSUrlSession session = null;
        NSUrlSessionConfiguration config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration("com.PolarisFTPUpload.BackgroundSession");
        session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, (NSUrlSessionDelegate)new MySessionDelegate(), new NSOperationQueue());
        string docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        docs = docs.Replace("/var", "file://var");
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(docs, "PolarisPictures2/VUPSXOUTA722002799CMC5022017103109544681088_1.jpeg");
        Console.WriteLine(filepath);
        string UploadURLString = "ftp://myftpUser:myftpPass@myftpIP:Port/Pictures/Database" + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.Day + "/";
        NSUrlSessionUploadTask uploadTask;
        NSUrl uploadURL = NSUrl.FromString(UploadURLString);
        NSUrlRequest req = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(uploadURL);
        uploadTask = session.CreateUploadTask(req, NSUrl.FromString(filepath));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither NSURLSession nor its predecessor, NSURLConnection, support the FTP PUT command.  The only Apple API that supports FTP uploads is CFFTPStream, which is ancient, deprecated, and strongly discouraged for new development.

Either way, you should not under any circumstances use FTP.  Period.  It is fundamentally impossible to make FTP secure, because passwords are sent in cleartext across the network.

Instead, you should write a simple bit of PHP code on your web server that accepts file uploads, and use HTTPS uploads.  Not only is that approach more secure, it is also supported with NSURLSession.

See [Secure PHP File Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950331/secure-php-file-upload-script) for more information on the web site of things, and see Apple's NSURLSession Programming Guide for help with the uploads on the iOS side.

Comment: I hear ya, unfortunately I'm not the arbiter of that decision, though, brother. I will say that you are 100% correct after a few days of reading Apple's documentation and have finally gotten my HTTP post upload working. I used a .NET Web API to do so and will hopefully be encompassing much more of my application's functionality here rather than FTP. We have some antiquated parts of our software that, I agree, need to be changed. Thanks, though! Definitely a proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There should be three `/` with `file` prefix. The prefix should be `file:///`, not `file://`.

You can just use `NSUrl.FromFilename(filepath)` to get this url without replacing the prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought the three slashes looked weird but after some digging yesterday said what the heck and tried it out. You were right, but I didn't know about the FromFilename method, so thanks. It doesn't appear that what I'm attempting to do is possible. It seems as if the only solution to my problem will be coding an aspx form and then posting into it through `NSUrlSession.CreateUploadTask` with proper form data.

Comment: There's a doc from Apple about uploading a file using URLSession, it use the POST http method. It may be the thing you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW28